# Aws giving blank screen using aws connect on elastic beanstalk instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been using the instance perfectly for about six months but now when I want to connect to the instance using AWS connect(the only option anyway) it is giving me a blank screen. i am using root account

below are images that may assist

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any modifications to SGs? The instance connect requires extensive inbound rules. Also `root` is not default user on EB. It is `ec2-user`.

Comment: try SSH client, It is an easier way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding network security access-group again, but I wonder how did they get revoked.